# How to access SVN through Mac OSX application

Tags: macos, svn, asihttprequest, nstask

I would like to access SVN through a new application I am building for Mac OS X platform, using native cocoa libraries. I believe, I need to invoke the SVN command-line application through NSTask, to run it in the background. I have two problems here

1. How to pass credentials to SVN?
2. How to check the status of SVN operation?

Any pointers will be of great help.

Comment: did you get any information regarding it... I am also looking for similar task!

Comment: no specific answers yet. But I am using NSTask to invoke SVN commands. Checking specific status is still an issue. please post if you come across a method.

Comment: hey I am using NSTask to, here is my code at github: https://github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/SVNLogger, but I am facing same problems which you faced, will share additional code, once resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.developer.html) and use Subversion's API to build your application.